# Turtle code not working, showing py-lint no member error

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

i believe i have coded everything correctly but i keep getting an error message saying, for example("Module 'turtle' has no 'reset' member)

```
import turtle

color = input('Enter a color:')

while (color != "QUIT"):
    turtle.reset()
    turtle.pencolor(color)
    turtle.pensize(10)

n = int(input('Enter a number:'))

if n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 == 0:
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(x=0, y=150)
    turtle.pendown()
    drawU(turtle.Turtle)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(x = 0, y = -10)
    turtle.pendown()
    drawH(t)
elif n % 3 == 0:
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(x=0, y=150)
    turtle.pendown()
    drawU(turtle.Turtle)
elif n % 5 == 0:
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(x=0, y=150)
    turtle.pendown()
    drawH(turtle.Turtle)
else:
    turtle.pencolor('black')



def drawU (t):
    turtle.setheading(270)
    turtle.forward(150)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(75)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(150)
```

each "turtle.____" shows as an error. i am not too sure what i am doing wrong. i included turtle.done() at the end as well, this is only half of my code.

Answer (score 0):

> i believe i have coded everything correctly

Far from it: termination of your loop depends on the value of `color` which never changes during the loop; you should be passing a turtle *instance* here `drawU(turtle.Turtle)` but are passing a turtle *class*;  your `else` clause makes no sense, effectively a no-op; your indentation as shown doesn't work; your `drawH()` function is missing.

Below is my attempt to reconstruct your intended code, but I can't be certain:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def drawU(turtle):
    turtle.setheading(270)
    turtle.forward(150)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(75)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(150)

def drawH(turtle):
    pass

color = input('Enter a color: ')

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

while color != "QUIT":

    n = int(input('Enter a number: '))

    turtle.reset()
    turtle.pencolor(color)
    turtle.pensize(10)

    if n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 == 0:
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setposition(x=0, y=150)
        turtle.pendown()
        drawU(turtle)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setposition(x=0, y=10)
        turtle.pendown()
        drawH(turtle)
    elif n % 3 == 0:
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setposition(x=0, y=150)
        turtle.pendown()
        drawU(turtle)
    elif n % 5 == 0:
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setposition(x=0, y=150)
        turtle.pendown()
        drawH(turtle)

    color = input('Enter a color: ')

screen.mainloop()
```